# Apache reverse proxy configuration from port 80 to port 8000

Tags: apache, server, port, reverse-proxy

Basically I want to forward all the traffic from port 80 to port 8000. 
Here is my config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ProxyPass / http://rentauto-sofia.com:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://rentauto-sofia.com:8000/

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: And what is the problem? What have you tried? What does not work? What error message do you get?

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't work. I have tried adding a ServerName and a ServerAlias as well. When II type out the domain in the URL I get an Internal ServerError. Here is the entire error: Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator ...

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at rentauto-sofia.com Port 80

Comment: here is the error.log: [warn] [pid 19133:tid 139672395179776] [client 195.234.87.26:26568] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
 [warn] [pid 19132:tid 139672511985408] [client 195.234.87.26:26570] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /favicon.ico. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule., referer: http://rentauto-sofia.com/

Comment: So, do you have a LoadModule directive with mod_proxy anywhere in your configuration?

Comment: No. I don't know what to do and will be glad if someone manages to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the following which are required modules for running apache proxy server

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_balancer
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
```

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank Youuuuuuuu! 

Comment: Glad to be of help to you :)